# How can I tell if my SVF2 translation is complete based on the manifest?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I would like to know how I can know when my SVF2 translation is complete based on the manifest.

1. Is there *any significant difference* between the manifest for an ***SVF translation versus an SVF2 translation***?
2. For an SVF2 translation, is it sufficient to say the ***translation is complete when*** the manifest shows: [SVF2 manifest sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9wwR.png)
3. Is there ***any intermediate stage*** during an SVF2 translation when the manifest will show outputType: SVF, status: success, progress: complete?

Answer (score 0):

As described on [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-svf2-enhancements-part-1-viewer)

> The Model Derivative service produces SVF2 derivatives by optimizing and sharing meshes within the same Viewable, and even across multiple Viewables when possible. Because of this optimization, SVF2 format reduces the Viewable storage size and speeds up viewing and loading performance.

We have also [this lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmii4iKbuHA) with more details.

The best way to know when your translation is ready is through [extraction.finished](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/extraction.finished/) event. Once the translation is complete, you'll receive a notification.

In this case, you need to follow [these steps](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-model-derivative/) and pass your workflow id to [POST Job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure).

During the translation, you'll also be able to check the progress through the manifest, and once it reaches `progress: "complete"` you should be able to retrieve your derivatives.